# extract only numbers from 2 places in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'input':['Age is 55 and 5 years', 'Age is 58','Age is 60.5','Age is 12 and 5 years',
                            'Age is 30.5 and 2 years of service']})
```

I need the desired output like below:

```
output:
=======
55,5
58
60.5
12,5
30.5,2
```

Tried code:

```
df = df.assign(A = lambda x: x['input'].str.extract('(\d+)'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use findall

```
#df=df.assign(A=df.input.str.findall('(\d+)'))#If you dont mind having them in list
df=df.assign(A=df.input.str.findall('(\d+)').str.join(','))#Rid them off the corner brackets

                     

                               input       A
0               Age is 55 and 5 years    55,5
1                           Age is 58      58
2                         Age is 60.5    60,5
3               Age is 12 and 5 years    12,5
4  Age is 30.5 and 2 years of service  30,5,2
```

Comment: I wanted to insert "," once it find the numbers from the first place and then append the number from the second place like 55,5.

Comment: @Karthik chengalvarayan, from your comments, not clear on what you need done

Comment: Eg: on  the last row, i wanted to have 30.5,2 not 30,5,2. I also wanted to maintain "."

Comment: Please try `df=df.assign(A=df.input.str.findall('(\d*\.?\d+)').str.join(','))`

Comment: Could you please consider accepting the answer. Click the up arrow on the left